# Having problems with jQuery removeClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having problems with jQuery .removeClass

I don't think i need to explain alot since the jsFiddle will do.
But why isn't left working propertly? Right is working fine as you see the red passes on correctly. But the left is jumping one and wont mark the last one.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      var currentDiv = 0;
    $('#arrowRight').click(function() {
        currentDiv = (currentDiv + 1) % 5;
        $('.dot').removeClass('active');
        $('.mark' + (currentDiv + 1)).addClass('active');
    }); 

    $('#arrowLeft').click(function() {
        currentDiv = currentDiv - 1;
        if (currentDiv < 0)
            currentDiv = 4;
        $('.dot').removeClass('active');
        $('.mark' + (currentDiv)).addClass('active');
    });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmDg8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your marks are numbers starting on 1, you got that right on arrowRight but on left you have to do

```
$('.mark' + (currentDiv + 1)).addClass('active');
```

note the `+ 1`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution that avoids counting elements and also binds one function that deals with moving in both directions.

**JavaScript**

```js
var $dots = $('.dot');

$('a').on('click', function() {
    var $current = dots.filter('.active');
    var goingRight = this.id === 'arrowRight';
    var $target = goingRight ? $current.next() : $current.prev();

    if ( !$target.length ) {
        $target = dots.filter( goingRight? ':first' : ':last' );
    }

    $current.removeClass('active');
    $target.addClass('active');

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="arrowLeft">Left</a>
<span class="dot mark1 active">Test</span>
<span class="dot mark2">Test</span>
<span class="dot mark3">Test</span>
<span class="dot mark4">Test</span>
<span class="dot mark5">Test</span>
<a href="#" id="arrowRight">Right</a>
```

Comment: I like your solution using `next()` and `prev()` did some refactor

Comment: @laconbass nice - much more efficient

Comment: Please edit your answer as your edit is being rejected because it is changing my answer too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it work this way -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#arrowRight').click(function () {
        var active = $('.dot.active');
        if (active.next('.dot').length > 0) {
            $('.dot').removeClass('active');
            active.next('.dot').addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('#arrowLeft').click(function () {
        var active = $('.dot.active');
        if (active.prev('.dot').length > 0) {
            $('.dot').removeClass('active');  
            active.prev('.dot').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/hmDg8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think why to complicate simple logic? pXL answer is great cause it is dynamic, but still a simple solution could be.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentDiv = 1;
        $('#arrowRight').click(function () {
            if (currentDiv < 5) {
                currentDiv++;
                $('.dot').removeClass('active');
                $('.mark' + (currentDiv)).addClass('active');
            }
        });

        $('#arrowLeft').click(function () {
            if (currentDiv > 1) {
                currentDiv--;
                $('.dot').removeClass('active');
                $('.mark' + (currentDiv)).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refactor a bit your logic making it simpler and reusable:

1. Cache the dots to avoid making new queries each time an arrow is clicked.
2. Cache a query with the active element rather than its index.
3. Use the same function for right and left arrows to keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
4. Use jQuery functions and special selectors for the *"what is the next?"* logic:

   - [$.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
   - [$.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
   - ':last' and ':first' selectors
   - [$.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
var $dots = $('.dot')
  , $current = $dots.filter('.active')
;
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var isRight = this.id === 'arrowRight';

    $current = $current[ isRight? 'next' : 'prev' ]( '.dot' );
    if ( !$current.length ) {
        $current = $dots.filter( isRight? ':first' : ':last' );
    }

    $dots.removeClass('active');
    $current.addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

This way you can remove `markX` classes as they are unneeded.

```html
<a href="#" id="arrowLeft">Left</a>
<span class="dot">Test</span>
<span class="dot active">Test</span>
<span class="dot">Test</span>
<span class="dot">Test</span>
<span class="dot">Test</span>
<a href="#" id="arrowRight">Right</a>
```

## [see it in action on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4E8BE/4/)